# React click button to render the page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

In the `renderList()`,  I have a delete button that will delete the content once it is clicked.  I am not sure where to put the `setState` so I put it inside on the `onClick()`. This doesn't work.  I would like to know if I am doing this correct or if there is a better way to solve this.

onClick Function

```
onClick={() => {
     this.props.deleteBook(list.book_id);
     this.setState({delete: list.book_id});
}}>
```

React.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { selectUser } from '../actions/index.js';
import { deleteBook } from '../actions/index.js';
import _ from 'lodash';

class myPage extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            delete: 0
        }
    }

    componentWillMount() {    
        this.props.selectUser(this.props.params.id);
    } 


    renderList() {
          return this.props.list.map((list) => {
            return (
                <li className='book-list'
                    key={list.book_id}>
                        {list.title}
                        <button
                        value={this.state.delete}
                        onChange={this.onClickChange} 
                        onClick={() => {
                            this.props.deleteBook(list.book_id);
                            this.setState({delete: list.book_id});
                        }}>
                        Delete
                        </button>

                </li>
            );
        })
    }

    render() {
        const {user} = this.props;
        const {list} = this.props;
        if(user) {

            return(
                <div>
                    <h2>Date Joined: {user.user.joined}</h2>
                    <h1>My Page</h1>
                    <h2>Username: {user.user.username}</h2>
                    <div>My Books:
                            <h1>
                                {this.renderList()}
                            </h1>
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    }
}
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return {
        user: state.user.post,
        list: state.list.all
    }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, { selectUser, deleteBook })(myPage);
```

Comment: You initialized the component state to `this.state = { delete: 0 }`. Does this represent the MyPage component being deleted or the Book being deleted? (Also your class `myPage` should be `MyPage`)

Comment: @styfle This is just dummy data and doesn't really do anything. I just put this.state = { delete: 0 } so the component re-renders once I click the delete button. This works but I need to go to another link and come back for the list of the books to go away. I wanted to find method where you click delete and the component renders so the selected book list disappears.

Comment: I thought setState re-renders the component but it doesn't seem to be rendering.

Comment: Please use componentDidMount instead of componentWillMount. Going forward that is the safer way to setup your components.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your use of `mapStateToProps`, seems like you are using Redux. Your list of books comes from the Redux store as `props` which is external to the component.

You do not need `this.state.delete` in the component. As state is managed by Redux, it seems like the bug is in your Redux code and not React code. Look into the reducers and ensure that you are handling the delete item action correctly.